# enter animation starts before leave animation has finished

Tags: vue.js

I would like to create a slide + fade transition for my vue routing. Here you can see the effect I want to achieve:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome

The "old" page slides to right and fades out, after that the "new" page fades in and slides to the left.

Currently I added a transition but the "new" container starts its animation before the "old" container has finished with its animation. I created a snippet to reproduce the problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/o1jkpkl75q

What needs to get fixed to get the desired transition animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `mode="out-in"` to the `transition`:

```
<transition name="slide-fade" mode="out-in">
```

Updated your CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit Vue Routing Example]